# Angular 2: Maximum Call Stack size exceeded(Lazy Loading)

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I have been implementing lazy loading, everything was working fine till some point but suddenly I am getting below error.

Any idea on what might be the possibilities

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
     at CatchSubscriber.OuterSubscriber [as constructor] (OuterSubscriber.ts:9)
     at new CatchSubscriber (catch.ts:48)
     at CatchOperator.call (catch.ts:35)
     at Observable.subscribe (Observable.ts:93)
     at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.ts:32)
     at MergeAllSubscriber._next (mergeAll.ts:86)
     at MergeAllSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
     at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:84)
     at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
     at ArrayObservable._subscribe (ArrayObservable.ts:124)
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a bit late....but for anyone having a similar problem in future,here it is:-

Actually this problem may arise cause of many reasons.

1.Recursive operations

2. The routing module where you have defined your routes , hasn't been included in the .module.ts file of that Module.

3.duplicate routes defined.

principally its cause of the 2nd reason.
So look out into your code for these errors.

Comment: Thanks! my problem was second reason!

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Comment: Thanks! #2 was the issue

Comment: #2 was the key!

Answer (score 3):

Probably you didn't have any routing for lazy loaded module.But always ensure you don't comment lines in route config files or any files that may cause lot of problem.Or you are doing some operation recursively.

If you can post the code then it will be easier to identify the cause.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks , In a hurry I included my module the in app module and also lazily loaded it (so it was recursive). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue, the reason was that I was missing the declaration of my routes in my LAZY module, in this case I am telling that for the relative path '' use the *RandomComponent* to load. and then add the reference in the 'imports', like this 'RouterModule.forChild(routes)'.

This is the code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { RandomComponent } from './random-component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    component: RandomComponent,
    path: ''
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    RandomComponent
  ]
})
export class RandomModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has a similar issue. Inspect your code properly. I added the module I was creating **SharedModule** in the import array, making it recursive. Removing it from the imports array, solved it.

```
import {Optional, SkipSelf, NgModule, OnDestroy, OnInit} from 
"@angular/core";
import {AppConfig} from "./conf/app-config";
import {UrlService} from "./url.service";
import {TranslateModule, TranslateService} from "ng2-translate";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@NgModule({
declarations:[],
imports:[SharedModule],
providers: [AppConfig, UrlService],
exports:[TranslateModule]
})
export class SharedModule implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

private subscription: Subscription;

constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: SharedModule,
           private _translate: TranslateService, private _route :ActivatedRoute ) {
if (parentModule) {
  throw new Error(
    'SharedModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
}

//add languages
_translate.addLangs(["en", "fr", "es", "zh"]);
_translate.setDefaultLang("en");


let browserLang = _translate.getBrowserLang();
_translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr|es|zh/) ? browserLang : "en")
}
}
```